# Number of ways to order elements from g groups in n spaces

Tags: probability

I want to know how many ways I can order combinations of the form AABCD in the 5 allotted spaces.

I thought it was n!/$g_1!g_2!g_3!$, where the $g_i$ represent the number of elements within the spaces that are in group i. This method  would yield an answer of 5!/2!

However, when I use this method to find the probability of a single pair in a 5 card hand, I get the wrong result.

using the above formula, I would guess the probability of a pair is (52*3*48*44*40/52*51*50*49*48) * 5!/2!

However, the correct answer is the value above/2.

Answer (score 1):

If you pretend the second A is distinct, like E, there are $5!$ orderings.  Each ordering of AABCD corresponds to two orderings of ABCDE, because you can swap A and E.  So there are $5!/2$.  Further thought should convince you that the useful way to represent this is $5!/2!$  You only divide by the factorials of the interchangeable groups.